# How to find particular documents from a collection with relationship/condition using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to display particular documents from a a collection in mongodb using Mongoose where the ref object `horario_id: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Horario'}`   must match a condition:

using the following:

```
Persona.find(
{
    horario_id : {$and: [ { empezar: { $lt : hora } }, { finalizar: { $gt: hora } } ]}

}
)
```

I get

```
{"message":"Can't use $and"}
```

Or must I do two queries: first to fetch the horario_id fields from "persona" document and 2nd to fetch data from "horario" collection?

**EDIT**: collections data example

persona collection:

```
[{"_id":"1","nombre":"foo","horario_id":"3"},
{"_id":"2","nombre":"bar","horario_id":"2"},
{"_id":"3","nombre":"oof","horario_id":"3"},
{"_id":"4","nombre":"rab","horario_id":"7"}]
```

horario collection

```
[{"_id":"1","empezar":"01:00","finalizar":"13:00"},
{"_id":"3","empezar":"03:00","finalizar":"15:00"},
{"_id":"7","empezar":"07:00","finalizar":"19:00"},
.....]
```

then, if `hora` = 14:00, then the query will display `persona` with `horario` ids = (1,3)

Comment: can you post your collection... And also `$and` is a top level operator and you used it in a wrong way here

Comment: thank you for your reply, I edited the question

Comment: What is your mongodb version? because you need to use `$lookup` aggregation here

Comment: it is version v3.4.7, on debian